# how to rename pdf file in external storage android programmatically?

Tags: android, pdf, file-rename, android-11, scoped-storage

I want to rename the PDF file and this file is not created by my app so how can I rename the pdf file in android? I'm using API levels 21 to 31.
I'm getting path using MediaStore Api like this

```
 val columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)
 val path = cursor.getString(columnData)
```

below 30 is a working fine. but in 30 and above when I am requesting file write permission for specific files **(createWriteRequest)** like this

```
    val pi = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, uriList)
        startIntentSenderForResult(
            pi.intentSender, 124,
            null, 0, 0, 0, null
        )
```

I have gotten an exception **IllegalArgumentException** check logcat.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All requested items must be Media items
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2450)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.createRequest(MediaStore.java:1115)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.createWriteRequest(MediaStore.java:1164)
```

I don't know why this occurs

Comment: What do you mean with that you have access to an uri? What kind of uri? Obtained how?

Comment: Below 30 you can rename as always.

Comment: val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.provider", File(path))
I'm getting uri like this

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing how you are obtaining `path`.

Comment: If you have a file path you should use the old routines to rename the file. If you cannot rename using file path then it makes no sense to use FileProvider to get an uri as file provider itself uses the path you give it and if you cannot rename then file provider will fail too. Or did you get that path from an earlier uri? Then use that uri.

Comment: @blackapps please check again I have edit my question

Comment: Soory, you did not give the info i asked for.

Comment: @blackapps thanks, right now I understand. I have solved it by using Old routine